# file io search until matches java

Tags: java, loops, netbeans, file-io

So I have accounts.txt file which includes

```
abcd
1234
efgh
5678
```

here is my code for searching

Scanner scan=null;

```
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(new File("accounts.txt"));

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String inpUser;
    inpUser = usernameTextField.getText();

    String inpPass;
    inpPass = pinNumberTextField.getText();

    String user="";
    if(scan.hasNextLine())
    user = scan.nextLine();

    String pass="";
    if(scan.hasNextLine())
    pass = scan.nextLine();

    if (inpUser.equals(user)&& inpPass.equals(pass)){
        accountGUI s = new accountGUI();
        s.setVisible(true);
    }else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Password / Username");
    }
```

If I run the program and try to input `efgh` and `5678` it will say wrong password / username because it only checks the first two lines in `accounts.txt`. How can I change the code so it checks whole file not just first two lines?

-- New Problem --
I have done this:

```
String user="";
String pass="";

while(scan.hasNextLine()){
user = scan.nextLine(); 
pass = scan.nextLine();
}
```

but now it skips the first two lines in accounts.txt and starts from line 3.

Comment: use while loop to read all lines instead of if condition.

Comment: @Omore thats working great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you had code that only checked the first two lines. This was a problem if the user trying to authenticate was not at the top of the file. Second, you tried the while loop, but the while loop goes through every line in the file until it gets to the end, and does not bother to check anything but the **last** two lines.

The while loop is close to correct, but you need to add a check that at every pair of lines, if that is the pair the user input, you authenticate them successfully. Then, we just keep track of whether we found the user - if we reach the end of the file without finding the right user, we show the error message.

```
String user="";
String pass="";

boolean foundUser = false; // Keeps track of if we found the user's credentials

while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
    // get username (we know it is there)
    user = scan.nextLine();

    // Get password, making sure to check it exists!
    if(scan.hasNextLine())
        pass = scan.nextLine();

    // If we have found the user's credentials, log in
    if (inpUser.equals(user) && inpPass.equals(pass)) {
        accountGUI s = new accountGUI();
        s.setVisible(true);
        foundUser = true;
        break; // We found the user, stop looping (stop looking)
    }
}

// If we've reached the end of the file, and not found the user
if(!foundUser)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Password / Username");
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use a while loop to read all input from the file.
Look at your code:

```
String user="";
if(scan.hasNextLine()) // if statement performs operation only once
user = scan.nextLine(); // this is the operation to perform once

String pass="";
if(scan.hasNextLine()) // if statement performs operation only once
pass = scan.nextLine(); // this is the operation to perform once
```

You are only reading the line once.
Try using while loop (multiple iterations) instead of if statement (once)

Comment: If i answered your question, please mark my answer as correct

Comment: I discovered an error. 
I have

`String user="";
        String pass="";
        
        
        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        user = scan.nextLine();    
        pass = scan.nextLine();

        }`
and it skips the first 2 lines. Why is that?

Comment: Please edit your original post with your new problem. Once you do that, comment here that you have done so and I will edit my original answer to help you. Please post all of your code in your edit though, or I cannot help.